# Xdebug: show more items in the call stack

Tags: xdebug

Xdebug's call stack shows 10 entries. Is there a way to show more? I didn't seem to find an option related to this in the documentation (http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered, it appears that 100, not 10 is the default maximum depth a call stack can reach. It is controlled by the xdebug.max_nesting_level variable:

> xdebug.max_nesting_level
>
> > Type: integer, Default value: 100
> >     Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection. The value of this 
> >     setting is the maximum level of nested functions that are allowed
> >     before the script will be aborted.
> >     http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

It won't work as a solution to control how many steps are shown in a call stack though. If this setting was for example used to limit the shown calls to 5, it would also mean that the script would fail after a nesting level of 5. Whether an actual error had occurred or not.

In conclusion: there is no mechanism in Xdebug that would be usable to control the amount of calls displayed once an actual error occurred.